# Build HTML page with output after GET and POST request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, blockchain

Firstly I´m relatively new to the whole Javascript and Node.js world. I´m working on a project to use the information of a GTIN database with an API on a webpage.

The ultimate goal is to get a table with information about the product mixed with a owner history safed in a private blockchain via public address after the input of the public address.

Right now I´m building the webpage without any blockchain connection.

For the Backend I´m using Express, BodyParser and Socket.io.

The problem with my code right now is, that firstly no css and no script files are loaded in the index.html and secondly after the submission of the UPC-Number the output is just written in the terminal.

Here is a example of the API I´m using:
https://www.upcitemdb.com/upc/884116064244

Here are my files I coded:

**server.js**

```
 //Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io     = require('socket.io')(server); 
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 3000!")
  });

var dir = __dirname;

var query;

//app.use('/client', express.static('client'))

//GET
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(dir + '/index.html');
});

//DBAPI - Works in Console
function DBAPI(gtin){
  console.log('Calling API')
  //API-Modul - Funktioniert in Konsole
  const https = require('https')

  var opts = {
    hostname: 'api.upcitemdb.com',
    path: '/prod/trial/lookup',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",     
    }
  }
  var req = https.request(opts, function(res) {
    console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers: ', res.headers);
    res.on('data', function(d) {
      console.log('BODY: ' + d);
    })
  })
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  })
  req.write('{ "upc": "' + gtin + '" }')
  req.end()
}


//POST
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var query=req.body.input1
    console.log('Server: In post request.')
    console.log(query);
    res.send(200);
    res.sendFile(dir + '/return.html');
    DBAPI(query);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('ready', function() {
        socket.emit('change_result', {result: query});
    });
});



//Data-Log File - Works
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/gtin.log', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;
console.log = function(d) { //
  log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blockchain-Service für Endkunden</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css/main.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/normalize.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/web3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/blockchainscripts.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>


        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                     </button>

                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blockchain-Service</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Angebotene Dienstleistungen <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="laptopservice.html">Laptop-Service</a></li>
                          <li><a href="containerservice.html">Isolations-Container-Service</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="aboutproject">Über das Projekt</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </header>


        <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Laptop-Service</h1>

        <p>

            <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000">
            <input type="test" name="input1" id="input1" placeholder="Eingabe GTIN">
            <input type="submit" id="button1" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </p>

        <p><div id="root"></div></p>

        <p onLoad="BuildHTMLTable('#excelDataTable')">
            <table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
            </table>
        </p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Mehr erfahren</a></p>
        </div>

        <footer>©2019 Blockchain-Projekt Gruppe 5</footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

**return.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blockchain-Service für Endkunden</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/css/main.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/normalize.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="scripts/web3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jsencrypt.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/blockchainscripts.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>


        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                     </button>

                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blockchain-Service</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Angebotene Dienstleistungen <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="laptopservice.html">Laptop-Service</a></li>
                          <li><a href="containerservice.html">Isolations-Container-Service</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="aboutproject">Über das Projekt</a></li>
                    </ul>


                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </header>


        <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Laptop-Service</h1>

        <p id="heading1">       
            Ergebnis:

        <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var socket = io();
            socket.emit('ready', function(data) {});
            socket.on('change_result', function(data) {
            document.getElementById('heading1').innerHTML = "Result: \""+data.result + "\"";
                });
            });
        </script>

        </p>
```

Sorry that the code is a little confusing, but atm I´m learning a lot trough try and error.

The error message I get in the developer tool from Google Chrome is following:
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxFBA.png)

After I input a UPC number in my browser tab, the only message I get is "OK" as you can see in Screenshot 2. [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwerB.png)

My structure ist as following:

```
C:\Users\timto\OneDrive\Desktop\website

---client<br>  
-------img<br>  
-------scripts<br>  
-----------blockchainscripts.js<br>  
-----------jsencrypt.min.js<br>  
-----------scripts.js<br>  
-----------web3.min.js<br>  
-------styles<br>  
-------gtin.log<br>  
---node_modules<br>  
---gtin.log<br>  
---index.html<br>  
---package.json<br>  
---package-lock.json<br>  
---return.html<br>  
---server.js<br>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Node.js/Express!

I think you should uncomment this line of code:

```
app.use('/client', express.static('client'))
```

and remove this block of code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(dir + '/index.html');
});
```

You should also put your `index.html` and `return.html` into your `./client` directory so that they are handled by the `express.static` code above.

The story we're trying to paint here is: "the directory structure of `./client` represents exactly how I would want users to access my static files through their browser." By putting your `index.html` and `return.html` inside the `./client` directory, you don't need to write any special code to serve those html files up (bc your `express.static` code is doing that for you).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I actually rebuild the whole server.js with Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the help. I actually rebuild the whole server.js with Postman.

So the code looks like this right now and is working:

```
    //Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'))

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 3000!")
  });

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var query=req.body.input1
    APIforInformation(query);
    console.log(query);
    res.end('success!')


});

function APIforInformation(gtin) {
  var request = require("request");

  var options = { method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup',
    headers: 
     { 'Postman-Token': 'ba74ee2a-0e16-4501-a668-34bc741bb576',
       'cache-control': 'no-cache',
       Authorization: 'Basic Og==',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: { upc: gtin },
    json: true };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      console.log(body);
    });

}
```

Now I´m stuck at the point to use the json file for posting information on my return.html.

The scripts.js for my index.html is still not loading and I don´t know why.